# How to create a favorite list with Vue js. Allowing the user to select maximun 5 options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

First of all, I'm new to programming and new to this channel so I'm sorry if the structure of my question is not correct. I can provide more details if needed. Thanks in advance for your help.

Context: I have a view with multiple options (buttons) where the user can select up to 5 of them. Once the user selects the fifth button all the other buttons should get disabled. If the user clicks again on one of the selected buttons, all the other buttons should get enabled again. How can I implement this logic?

I'm using vue js and vuetify.

It's probably not the best solution but I once the user clicks on a button I change the class of that button so it looks as if it was active. Then I count the amount of buttons that have been clicked to disable the rest of the buttons (this is not working).

```
 <v-layout>
      <v-flex row wrap>
        <v-card class="interests__content">
          <!-- looping through interests array -->
          <!-- with :class i'm binding classes to change the color of the buttons, with @click="increase()" i'm calling the increase method -->
          <v-tooltip color="primary" top v-for="interest in interests" :key="interest.name">
            <v-btn
              v-model="selected"
              flat
              slot="activator"
              :class="{blue:interest.checked, interest__btn: !interest.checked}"
              @click="increase(interest)"
              :disabled="disabled"
              :checked="checked"
            >{{interest.name}}</v-btn>

            <span>{{interest.name}}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
      selected: "",
      count: 0,
      disabled: false,
      interests: [
        { name: "Interest1", checked: false },
        { name: "Interest2", checked: false },
        { name: "Interest3", checked: false },
        { name: "Interest4", checked: false },
        { name: "Interest5", checked: false },
        { name: "Interest6", checked: false },
        { name: "Interest7", checked: false },
        { name: "Interest8", checked: false },
        { name: "Interest9", checked: false },


      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increase: function(interest) {
      this.count += 1;
      //changing the value of checked to add the blue class, with this class I add the background color to the button as if it was active.
      interest.checked = !interest.checked;

      if (this.count > 4) {
        this.disabled = !this.disabled;
      }
    },
    // I'm trying to check if the button has a class to implement the logic
    checkIfClass: function(interest) {
      interest.checked = !interest.checked;

      if (interest.classList.contains("blue"));
    }
  },
  computed: {}
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.interest__btn {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: white;
  color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #0091da;
  text-transform: none;
}
.interest__btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgba(172, 196, 221, 0.7);
}
.interests__content {
  padding: 1.7em;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #0091da;
  color: white !important;
  text-transform: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Vue way of doing this is to have all the state of your application in js (your `interests` array), then to make everything that handles the display of this state *reactive*. In practice this means using `computed` rather than `methods` for everything that turns state into pixels on screen.

In da old days, we would have looped through `interests` to count the number checked. In 2019 we'll use reduce(), so...

```
computed:{
    numChecked(){
        return this.interests.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc += curr.checked?1:0,0)
    }
}
```

Then in your template...

```
:disabled="(numChecked > 5 && !interest.checked)?'disabled':''"
```

Comment: If you title the answer as `the Vue way of doing...` one would expect you using computed properties again instead of the long condition :)

Comment: @DhananjaiPai yup. The trouble is that OP's child component in the for loop, where you might add the computed property, is Vuetify. So I think it's not really worth wrapping it just for this test. I agree that my disabled test is about the limit of what you want to see in a template.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @bbsimonbb, unfortunately once I implement the code you have provided all the buttons get disabled. How could I possibly fix that?

Comment: Grub down. The :disabled test must always return true. Is numChecked working? Log it to the console or put it on screen. If you take out the second part of the test, does it work? Have you got the Vue devtools chrome extension ?

Comment: All the buttons have the class disabled by default: <button data-v-002dfb20="" disabled="disabled" type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--disabled v-btn--flat theme--light interest__btn"><div class="v-btn__content">Interest1</div></button>

Comment: I'm working on my work laptop and can not install the chrome extension, will see if the numChecked is working

Comment: The :disabled is always evaluating to true. The buttons always get the class disabled. Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a solution, basically using a watcher to know when the counter was greater than 5 and adding another value-pair to handle the disable property:
     `

> {{interest.name}}

```
            <span>{{interest.name}}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
      selected: "",
      count: 0,
      disabled: false,
      interests: [
          { name: "Interest1", checked: false, disabled: false },
          { name: "Interest2", checked: false, disabled: false },
          { name: "Interest3", checked: false, disabled: false },
          { name: "Interest4", checked: false, disabled: false },
          { name: "Interest5", checked: false, disabled: false },
          { name: "Interest6", checked: false, disabled: false },
          { name: "Interest7", checked: false, disabled: false },

      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increase: function(interest) {
      //changing the value of checked to add the blue class, with this class I add 
      the background color to the button as if it was active.
      interest.checked = !interest.checked;

      if (interest.checked) {
        this.count++;
      } else {
        this.count--;``
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    count: function(n, o) {
      if (this.count > 4) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.interests.length; i++) {
         if (!this.interests[i].checked) {
            this.interests[i].disabled = true;
          } else {`
            this.interests[i].disabled = false;
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.interests.length; i++) {
          this.interests[i].disabled = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.interest__btn {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: white;
  color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #0091da;
  text-transform: none;
}
.interest__btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgba(172, 196, 221, 0.7);
}
.interests__content {
  padding: 1.7em;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #0091da;
  color: white !important;
  text-transform: none;
}
</style>
```